# Does JBoss Support Comets

Tags: jboss

Does JBoss support Comets, if so do you know where I can get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do Comet by using the HTTP NIO (non-blocking IO) connector in Tomcat (JBoss after all uses Tomcat for its web serving).

What version of JBoss are you using?

Some resources:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-nioserver/